# SLComposeServiceViewController height issue

Tags: ios, swift, slcomposeviewcontroller

My Share extension's view height seems to be rendered smaller than needed to accommodate the SLComposeSheetConfigurationItem. as you can see in attachment, it seems to be cut off from the bottom ("to: test@email.com") and I have to scroll it to see it all. Any idea why it might be happening. I am not customizing it in any way.[image: screenshot]

Comment: you should post some code to check

Comment: Also could not get the part of the UI in which you are getting issue! It would be great if you can post a gif.

Comment: If you look at the bottom part "To: test@email.com", it is not vertically centred.

Comment: Which device are you using ?

Comment: Tested on iPhone XS

Answer (score 2):

`SLComposeServiceViewController` stored `SLComposeSheetConfigurationItem` in `tablView`, so you need to access `tableView` by travelling on `subView` and call `scrollToRow` for bottom position will fix your issue.

**Solution 1:**

Add following code in `ShareViewController`.

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)

    if let slSheet = self.children.first as? UINavigationController,
        let tblView = slSheet.children.first?.view.subviews.first as? UITableView
    {
            // Scroll tablView to bottom
            tblView.scrollToRow(at: IndexPath(row: 0, section: 0), at: .bottom, animated: true)
    }
}
```

**Solution 2:**

Change the row height will fix your issue, But make sure it is exactly height value which you want, I have used as per my requirements. Default value is 44.

```
tblView.rowHeight = 35
tblView.separatorStyle = .none
```

Comment: Okay, Let me know if there are any query.

Comment: It moves the whole scrollview up. Even though the configuration item shows properly now, the top of text view with the cursor is now a bit cut off from the top.

Comment: For some reason, row height does not take effect.

Comment: Is there any way to change the height of the view containing the Image and Text?

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be an issue with iOS 13. The sheet's height is controlled by the system. Setting the `preferredContentSize` property doesn't have any effect. I'm using the following workaround:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    if #available(iOS 13.0, *) {
        _ = NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(forName: UIResponder.keyboardDidShowNotification, object: nil, queue: .main) { (_) in
            if let layoutContainerView = self.view.subviews.last {
                layoutContainerView.frame.size.height += 10
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The last `subview` of `self.view` is an instance of `UILayoutContainerView`, which is a private UIKit class. This class determines the size of the share dialog, but doesn't have any constraints attached to it. Therefore I have to set the `frame` property directly. I'm using the `keyboardDidShowNotification` callback because the `frame` is updated by the system when the keyboard appears.

If anyone comes up with a better solution, please let me know.

Comment: Ok i will try it tmrw

Comment: it does work. It's just that the frame resize is visible. I wish it would resize the frame before displaying it.